# Vim keybinding inside Chrome DevTools

Tags: vim, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to use the supper handy (<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>vi</kbd>, etc) inside [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools)?

More precisely the source panel and console?

I'm using Vimium, which is great, but when doing web dev in the Chrome DevTools I can't use any vi action.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Developer Advocate for DevTools here. This is not currently possible. [Open a bug](https://crbug.com) if you want this feature. Please link to the bug if you open one, so that others can star it and comment on it. I'd recommend scoping it to the Sources panel, only. Otherwise it'd probably be too big of an undertaking.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013831

Answer (score 4):

There are *still no vim keybindings available in the Chrome Dev Tools* settings, in the opposite to the Firefox Developer Tools, where you currently can choose between standard, emacs, vim and sublime text keybindings out of the box.

However, there is some node.js solution, which allows to remote control the Chrome Dev Tools from neovim, see [vim-chrome-devtools](https://github.com/carlosrocha/vim-chrome-devtools). It may serve as an alternative until Google perhaps some day provides Vim support.

By the way, I thought, Bram Moolenaar, the Developer of Vim, is still hired by Google? ...

Answer (score -3):

Vimium - The Hacker's Browser. Vimium provides keyboard shortcuts for navigation and control in the spirit of Vim.

[here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en)

Comment: It does not support chrome dev-tools.